# DML and callout in same future

Tags: apex, dml

I need to do a call-out to get a token on the trigger. In this case, you need to save this token through the DML operation.
Callout and trigger cannot be performed in one operation. How can I make a call out and save the token for further use in subsequent callouts?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot perform DML *before* making a callout. However, you can save records after the callout is complete. Order them properly and your asynchronous method will work.

Comment: I try to do it after callout but catch error. Do you have some example. Thank you

Comment: after callout complete i cannot return the callout result and savw it out side callout

Comment: @AltiriResb You'll need to share the details with us (including the full text of the error message, and the code that you're currently using). You should edit your question to include that (though it might be different enough to warrant an entirely new question).